# how to declare UInt32 variable with global class access

Tags: iphone, ios, uint32

I am trying to declare a UInt32 variable that can be accessed by any method in the class..

so its global to the classes methods but not to any other class...

I am trying to do it like this in the .h

```
@interface EngineRequests : NSObject {

    UInt32 dataVersion;
}

@property (copy) UInt32 dataVersion;
```

but thats not working.. I'm getting an error on the line @property etc.. do I even need that or is it fine to just use the UInt32 at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
@interface EngineRequests : NSObject {
@protected
   UInt32 dataVersion;
}

@property (assign) UInt32 dataVersion;
@end

@implementation EngineRequests

@synthesize dataVersion;

// methods can access self.dataVersion

@end
```

But you don't really need the property, unless you want to grant/control outside access. You could just declare `UInt32 dataVersion` in the class interface and then reference `dataVersion` in the implementation without `self.` Either way, `@protected` will prevent outside classes from accessing `dataVersion` directly.

Have you read up on [Objective-C Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)?

***Initialization***

Your `EngineRequests` is a subclass of `NSObject`. As such, you can (usually should) override `NSObject`'s `-(id)init` method, like such:

```
-(id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self != nil) {
      self.dataVersion = 8675309; // omit 'self.' if you have no '@property'
   }
   return self;
}
```

Or create your own `-(id)initWithVersion:(UInt32)version;`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, say if i had a method that was going to initalize that UInt32 var via a parameter, how would I do that?

I have tried this **- (void) initalizePacketVariables:(UInt32)version
{//...**

However thats causing errors..

Comment: Added an update. The method you describe in your comment would work fine too. The `init` stuff is best practice in Cocoa.

Comment: okay cool.. I will try and figure this all out then. thanks for the help

Comment: just realized why it wasnt working.. where i was decalring my method I had not changed to just (UInt32) i still had (UInt32 *).. how many times before I lear that trick. lol

Comment: Oops, yes, I guess you want the real value. Thanks for the props!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable only inside interface to make it visible to all classes methods. Creating the getter-setter using @property.... will make it class variable and it will be visible outside the class. you have to do just this.

@interface EngineRequests : NSObject {

```
UInt32 dataVersion;
```

}

nothing more.